# Convert .Net Compact Framework 3.5 to .Net Core

Tags: .net, compact-framework, .net-core, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

Is there a way I can easily see what portions of my .Net Compact Framework codebase are tied to things outside of .Net Core in order to assist a move over the .Net Core Framework?

I'm trying to move off of Windows CE and onto Linux with only writing as little code as needed.

Comment: You can start with targeting the .Net Core, and see what classes aren't available for.

Comment: You could try using the [.Net portability analyzer](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport).

Comment: Windows CF is not supported by the portability analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up stubbing/commenting out all CF code to create a .Net framework (proper) build.

However the analyzer obviously was unable to see what wasn't compatible that was commented out.